# PHP: How to display multiple MySQL table records per HTML table row using MySQLi

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, database

I would like to display a group of elements in a row in php from mysql database. I already did it, but my data appears in one long column. I would like every new element to appear one next to the other.

Here is a screenshot of what I get. I would like to the first one to be next to the second one:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/2y3g0n7hqrjp8oz/Capture.PNG?dl=0

Here is my code:

```
    <?php
    require_once 'core/init.php';
    include 'includes/navigation.php';

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM interviews WHERE featured = 1";
    $featured = $db->query($sql);


    <html>
```

`enter code here`
`enter code here`

```
    <link href="http://localhost/menu/css/academy.css" rel="stylesheet" `enter code here`type="text/css" />
```

```
    <?php while($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($featured)) : ?>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th>
        <div id="element1"></div>
        <div id="content1">

            <img src="<?= $product['image']; ?>" alt="<?= $product['title']; ?>">
            <h4><?= $product['title']; ?></h4>
            <hr>
            <p class="description"><?= $product['description']; ?></p>

    <!--------BUTTON 3-------->
    <div id="hovers">
        <a href="#" class="button">
            <span class="contentbut"> Read More</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    </th>
</tr>
    </table>    
    <?php endwhile; ?>      
    </div>
</div>
```

Please, help.

Thank you!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136825/discussion-on-question-by-kaloyan-how-to-display-data-from-mysql-database-in-a-r).

Comment: Yes. It worked well. Thank you for sharing your knowledge here. I am now working on a register form so that people can register to my site. I managed to get an user to the database but was not able to get a verification email sent to my email.

Comment: Yes. I really appreciate your help. You are an expert!:)

Comment: Ok. I just did it. I am trying to make some changes. Hope it is not a problem to ask you if i have any questions. Thank you.

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge May I ask you how I can extract the number of interviews from each category? For Example I would like to get the total amount of interviews, but when I click on apps to get only the count of Apps interviews.

Comment: Here are my queries:     <?php
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM interviews WHERE featured = 1";
      $featured = $db->query($sql);
      $count=mysqli_num_rows($featured);
      
     
      $sqlapps = "SELECT * FROM interviews WHERE categories = 1";
      $featuredapps = $db->query($sqlapps);
      $countapps=mysqli_num_rows($featuredapps);
     ?>

Comment: Here is how i pring them on the screen:     <div class="number">
     Showing: 

     <?php echo $count?> of <?php echo $count?>
    
    </div>

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge I make a different page for each category. Not sure if that is a good way to do it.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137248/bulgaria-u-s-a-lamp-dev

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge I am not able to chat in a room. Can you check my files. I have a screenshot where if I click on "Apps" I would like to see the number of the interviews showing like in the screenshot here. Can you help me? Thanks: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xxc65dh427vk0od/AAAMsA3Q8fv7czpehqn6Vedaa?dl=0

Comment: @Anthony Rutledge Did you have the chance to take a look at the categories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Introduction

**Note**: This answer details creating a *many-records-to-one-row* arrangement. However, this answer can be altered to provide a *single-record-to-one-row* arrangement.

*Separating concerns* will help you write cleaner code. Separating concerns will make it easier to maintain your code. Clean code is *loosely coupled*, unburdened by embedded dependencies. Clean code identifies its dependencies in *function signatures* and *class constructors* with the expectation that these needs will be fulfilled externally. Clean code has *tight cohesion*. This means functions/methods have a single task, and classes have a single objective. Clean code is often reflected in a task that has been broken down and refined (but, not always). Clean code is an ideal I strive for, but no one is perfect.

Try to think of ways to get as much ***SQL*** and ***PHP*** out of your ***HTML*** files. Interpolating variables and showing the return results of functions only can make your HTML much easier to read. *Good HTML structure* counts, too.

Breaking down the task of dynamically building a `<table>` based on the results of a SQL query is very possible. Eventually, you may decide to use *CSS* and *divs* for styling and responsiveness reasons. This code can be altered to achieve this (after all, you'd just be stacking boxes in rows).

*Eventually*, creating an OOP class (with custom namespaces) would be great for modularizing your code and getting the vast majority of your symbols (variable names, etc) out of the *global namespace*.

---

### Before we get going: php.ini: include_path

Do you want to setup a logical directory architecture for your project?

*Set the `include_path` inside of `php.ini`.*

If you search your `php.ini` for the `include_path` setting, you can set this to one directory, or any group of appropriate directories. This way, you can arrange your files in directories the way you desire, and your `include`, `include_once`, `require`, and `require_once` statements will still find the files they want to import. You will not have to type absolute paths like`/dir/dir/file.php` or relative paths like `../../core/database.php`. In both cases, you could just specify the filename.

Example:

```
include 'file.php';     //Finds the file if it is in the include_path.
require 'database.php'; //Finds the file if it is in the include_path.
```

**Note**: Keep library files and other pure PHP coding files (etc ...) out of the webroot, or any publicly accessible directories. Keep them logically above the webroot. Set the `include_path` so you do not have to keep doing `../../blah/foo` all of the time.

---

### Tasks

**1**) First, make a function for getting an instance of a `mysqli_result` object.

```
/**
 * Returns a string, or
 * throws an UnexpectedValueException, otherwise.
 */
function isString($string)
{
    if (!is_string($string)) {
        throw new UnexpectedValueException("$string must be a string data type.");
    }

    return $string;
}

/**
 * Returns a mysqli_result object, or throws an `UnexpectedValueException`.
 * You can reuse this for other SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries.
 */
function getMySQLiResult(MySQLi $db, $sql)
{
    $result = $db->query(isString($sql));

    if (!($result instanceof mysqli_result)) {
        throw new UnexpectedValueException("<p>MySQLi error no {$db->errno} : {$db->error}</p>");
    } 

    return $result;
}
```

**2**) Second, make a function to house your SQL and invoke getMySQLiResult().

```
/**
 * Make sure you can get the data first.
 * returns a mysqli_result object.
 */
function getInterviews(MySQLi $db)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `interviews` WHERE `featured` = 1";
    return getMySQLiResult($db, $sql);
}
```

**3**) Make a function for building a table data (`<td></td>`) cell and its content.  Put *all* HTML or data that you need to ***repeat for each record*** in here.

```
/**
 * Returns one database table record a table data cell.
 */
function buildCell(array $record)
{
    return "<td>\n".
                '<img src="' .$record['image']. '" alt="' .$record['title']. '">' ."\n".
                '<h4>' .$record['title']. '</h4>' . "\n" .
                '<hr>' . "\n" .
                '<p class="description">' .$record['description']. '</p>' . "\n" .
                '<div id="hovers">
                     <a href="#" class="button">
                         <span class="contentbut">Read More</span>
                     </a>
                 </div>' . "\n 
            </td>\n";
}
```

**4**) Make a function for building table rows. Be wary of partial rows. :-)

*First*, a little helper function.

```
/**
 * Returns one <tr></tr> element. Helper.
 */
function makeTr($tds)
{
    return "<tr>\n" .isString($tds). "\n</tr>";
}
```

*Second*, the real deal.

```
function buildTableRow (array $tableRow)
{
    return makeTr(buildCell($tableRow)) . "\n";   //Done!
}

/**
 * Returns a string of multiple <tr></tr> elements,
 * $maxRecords per row.
 */
function buildTableRows(array $tableRows, $numRecords, $maxPerRow)
{
    $rows          = []; // Holds finished groups of <tr>s
    $row           = ''; // Temporary variable for building row of <td>s
    $numCells      = 0;  // Number of cells currently in a row of <td>s.
    $numRows       = (int)($numRecords / $maxPerRow); //Rows to make.
    $numStragglers = $numRecords % $maxPerRow;        // Extra <td>s, partialRow.

    if ($numStragglers !== 0) {  //Check if extra row is needed.
        $numRows += 1;
    }

    foreach ($tableRows as $record)
    {
        $row .= buildCell($record);
        ++$numCells;

        if ($numCells === $numRecords) {  // Builds partial, last row, if needed.
            $rows[] = makeTr($row);
            break;                        // Done!
        }

        if ($numCells === $maxPerRow) {   // Builds full row.
            $rows[]   = makeTr($row);     // Save the row.
            $numCells = 0;                // Start cell counter over.
            $row      = '';               // Start a new row.
        }
    }

    if(count($rows) !== $numRows) {  //Verify all rows were created.
        throw new RuntimeException("Rows (<tr>) for all records were not created!");
    }

    return  implode("\n", $rows) . "\n";  //Return all rows as a string.
}
```

**5**) Make a function that spits out the HTML you need on your page. In this case, you only need one (1) substitution to appear in the HTML.

```
/**
 * returns a set of HTML table rows (<tr></tr>) to fill a <tbody>.
 * or, returns an alternative message.
 */
function drawInterviews(MySQLi $db, $maxPerRow) //PDO is recommened. Dependency injection.
{
    $defaultMessage = "<tr>\n<td>There are no featured interviewers.<td>\n<\tr>\n";

    try {
           if (!is_int($maxPerRow) || $maxPerRow < 1) {
              throw new RangeException("The number of interviews per row must be an integer equal to 1, or greater than 1.");
           }

           //Make a robust connection sequence, or pass it in like above.
           //$db       = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'password', 'dbname');
           $result     = getInterviews($db);
           $numRecords = result->num_rows;

           if ($numRecords < 1) {
               return $defaultMessage;
           }

           if ($numRecords === 1) {
               return buildTableRow($result->fetch_assoc()); 
           }                

           return buildTableRows($result->fetch_all(), $numRecords, $maxPerRow);

    } catch (Exception $e)
         //Something went wrong with the query.
         error_log($e->getMessage());
    } finally { //PHP 5.5+
        $result->free();
    }

    return $defaultMessage;
}
```

**6**) Now, have a good HTML `<table>` structure. Only one interpolation needed. Assuming three `<td>`s (records) per row ...

Anyway, if you want a table, put a copy of this table "skeleton" inside of **`academytest.php`**, somewhere between the *header* and the *footer* (i.e. the main `<body>` of the HTML document).

```
<table>
    <caption>Featured Interviewers</caption> <!-- Centers above table. -->
    <thead>
        <tr>                  <!-- If needed. -->
            <th>Heading1</th> <!-- If needed. -->
            <th>Heading2</th> <!-- If needed. -->
            <th>Heading3</th> <!-- If needed. -->
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot></tfoot>           <!-- If needed. Yes, it goes after <thead>. -->
    <tbody>
        <!-- <div id="element1"></div> --> //What goes between here?
        <!-- <div id="content1">       --> //What's this? 
        <?= drawInterviews($db, 3); ?>  <!-- Dependency injection. -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

All of this can be made more modular and reusable (object-oriented, even).

---

### Update:

Based on your Dropbox code ...

### academytest.php

**1**) The best thing to do is create a separate PHP file named `tbodyFiller.php`, or something to that effect. Put all the functions in this file, ***except*** for `getInterviews()` and `drawInterviews()` which will go into `academyLibray.php`, `isString()` which will go into `library.php`, and `getMySQLiResult()` which will go in `database.php` (formerly `init.php`).

The *beginning* of `academytest.php` should look like this:

```
<?php
//                       academytest.php
require '../../includes/library.php';    //For now, put generic helper functions here. Group them, later.
require_once '../../core/database.php';  //Formerly, init.php. Put getMySQLiResult() in here.
require '../../includes/academyLibrary.php'; //Put the two "interview"  functions here.

$db = getMySQLi();  //Many things are dependent on this being here.

require '../../includes/navigation.php';

/***************** DELETE THESE LINES *****************/
//$sql = "SELECT * FROM interviews WHERE featured = 1";
//$featured = $db->query($sql);
/******************************************************/
```

In the footer of `academytest.php`, close the connection to your database.

```
<!-- ------FOOTER------ -->
<?php
    include '../../includes/footer.php';
    $db->close(); //Ensures $db is available to use in the footer, if necessary.
?>
```

---

### library.php

The *beginning* of `library.php` should look like this:

```
<?php
//                       library.php

/**
 * Returns a string, or
 * throws an UnexpectedValueException, otherwise.
 */
function isString($string)
{
    if (!is_string($string)) {
        throw new UnexpectedValueException("$string must be a string data type.");
    }

    return $string;
}
```

---

I think `init.php` should be named `database.php`. You can learn to use the object oriented constructor (using `new`) sequence with error checking at your leisure.  Eventually, you will want to learn [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Also, make a separate file to hold your credentials. Right now, this is better than hard coding them in to the `getMySQLi()` function.

### dbCreds.php

```
<?php

//                        dbCreds.php

$host     =  ''; //IP or DNS name: string.
$username =  ''; //Your account: string.
$passwd   =  ''; //The password: string.
$dbname   =  ''; //The database you want to work with: string.

//*************************************************************************
//$port   =  '3306'; //Un-comment and change only if you need a differnt TCP port. 
                     //Also, you would need to add a $port as your last argument in new MySQLi(),
                     //in the getMySQLi() function.
```

---

### database.php

```
<?php
//                       database.php
/**
 * Returns a mysqli_result object, or throws an `UnexpectedValueException`.
 * You can reuse this for other SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries.
 */
function getMySQLiResult(MySQLi $db, $sql)
{
    $result = $db->query(isString($sql));

    if (!($result instanceof mysqli_result)) {
        throw new UnexpectedValueException("<p>MySQLi error no {$db->errno} : {$db->error}</p>");
    } 

    return $result;
}

function getMySQLi() //This can be improved, but that's not the issue right now.
{
    require_once 'dbCreds.php'; //Choose your own file name. Do not put in public directory.

    $db = new mysqli($host, $username, $passwd, $dbname); //$port would be next.

    if(!($db instanceof MySQLi)){
        throw new UnexpectedValueException("A MySQLi object was not returned during your connection attempt.");
    }

    if(isset($db->connect_error)){
        throw new UnexpectedValueException("The database connection was not established. {$db->connect_errno} : {$db->connect_error}");
    }

    return $db
}  //Using the object form of MySQLi object has side benenfits.
```

---

### academyLibrary.php

The *beginning* of `academyLibrary.php` should look like this:

```
<?php
//                       academyLibrary.php
require 'tbodyFiller.php'; //Put all but four functions in here.

function getInterviews(MySQLi $db)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `interviews` WHERE `featured` = 1";
    return getMySQLiResult($db, $sql);
}

/**
 * Comments //etc...
 */
function drawInterviews(MySQLi $db, $maxPerRow)
{
    //The code, etc ...
}
```

If you have not configured your `include_path` inside of the `php.ini`, make sure `academyLibrary.php` and `tbodyFiller.php` are located in the ***same*** directory.

---

### navigation.php

We are going to replace the procedural forms of working with MySQL with the object-oriented ones. This is simple, and we do not need to change much. I will not replace your loops or queries at this time, but my advice is to *get out of the habbit* of putting PHP loops and SQL *directly* in your HTML. Find a way to use a function or method, like I did for the table's  in `academytest.php`. By this time, you should have enough examples. :-)

**Refactoring**

I took some time to refactor this file. Here is what I have at the top. *Once again*, you may wish to create another PHP file, say `navLibrary.php`, and put these functions into it. In that case you would replace all the functions seen below with one line, `require 'navLibrary.php';`. Naturally, this way of importing code may depend on configuring your `include_path` inside of the `php.ini`.

```
<?php
//                    navigation.php    

function getPqueryMainData(MySQLi $db)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `mainmenu` WHERE `parent` = 0";       //pqueryMain
    return getMySQLiResult($db, $sql);
}

function getPqueryData(MySQLi $db)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `categories` WHERE `parent` = 0";     //pquery
    return getMySQLiResult($db, $sql);
}

function getCquery1Data(MySQLi $db)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `categories` WHERE `parent` = 1";     //cquery1
    return getMySQLiResult($db, $sql);
}

function getCquery2Data(MySQLi $db, $int)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `categories` WHERE `parent` = '$int'"; //cquery2
    return getMySQLiResult($db, $sql);
}

//Consider doing at most 3 queries early on.
//Consider using better names for your variables.
//I get that 'p' means "primary", and 'c' means "child", but come on. :-) 

$pqueryMain = getPqueryMainData($db);
$pquery     = getPqueryData($db);
$cquery1    = getCquery1Data($db);
$cquery2    = null;
```

Comment: For some reason I get un error saying that "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$result' (T_VARIABLE)"      

That is weird, because I define it on top in core/init.php file:
<?php
 require_once '../../core/init.php';
 include '../../includes/navigation.php';
?>


<?php
 /**
 * Make sure you can get the data first.
 * returns a mysqli_result object, or throws and exception.
 */
function getInterviews()
{
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM interviews WHERE featured = 1";
 $featured = $db->query($sql);

    return $featured;
}
?>

Do you know why is that?

Comment: Checking .... it does not think that `$result` is an instance of the `mysqli_result` class?

Comment: No, successful `SELECT` queries should return a `mysqli_result` object. Use `var_dump()` on the result of the query to see what kind of value you get back.

Comment: Hey, I had a variable named wrong in the `throw` statement. Now look at `getInterviews()`.

Comment: Also, the database connection has not been established in my script. Instantiate a `mysqli `object and pass it to `getInterviews()`.

Comment: My database connection is established in my file init.php and then i include it in the main php file with include "init.php". Thank you for your answers. Will see what i can do tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: All you have to do is pass your `MySQLi` object into `$getInterviews()` like I've shown. Or, if your `MySQLi` object is in the `GLOBAL` namespace, pass it to `drawInterviews()` instead, like this `drawInterviews($mysqli)`. I'll post the code.

Comment: @Kaloyan I fixed several more logic errors. I think this should work now.

Comment: What an effort. You must really like helping people. Very robust. I can see room for improvement, but you've noted that.

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge Thank you for sharing that code here. I really appreciate it. Unfortunately, I am still not able to run the code successfuly.   At the end where you call <?= drawInterviews($mysqli, 3); ?>, I changed it to <?= drawInterviews($db, 3); ?>, but i got an error that buildCell function is undefined. Can I share all of my files here and you help me figure out what I am missing. I am sending you my init.php file where I connect to the database, nav.php (for the menu), css file and main php file: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ytcp76x53yhh4uh/AAAS05EClKZ50LzijkNFJSIya?dl=0

Comment: Ok, good deal. We just need to load up these function before drawInterview() is executed. The $db handle (which must be a MySQLi object) must be instantiated before drawInterview() is executed.

Comment: @Kaloyan What version of PHP are you using. You need PHP 5.5+ for some of my code (the `finally` part of my `try\catch\finally` blocks requires PHP 5.5 or above).

Comment: I will check but i think it is not 5.5. Maybe i have to upgrade it.

Comment: @Kaloyan `phpinfo()`  is one way to check the version. Also, we can just lose the `finally` block in `drawInterviews()` if you are on 5.4 or below. If you are on 5.3 or below, the `[ ]` array syntax would have to change back to `array( )`. Yikes!

Comment: @Kaloyan I got rid of $db->close(); in the finally block in `drawInterviews()`  Also, I added information about what the "footer" of `academytest.php` should look like in the **Update**. I'm done for now. Let me know how it goes. I'm sure I've given you quite a few ideas. I learned them from reading, writing code, and others. It's only fair I pass on what I know.

Comment: @Kaloyan Make sure you supply your actual credentials to getMySQLi. I usually use a `require dbCreds.php` inside of the method responsible for creating database connections. That way, I do not have to put my actual credentials in the side of the database connection routine. Just make some variables and stick them in a file of your choosing.

Comment: @Kaloyan I updated getMySQLi  as noted. Let me know how it goes. Should get an instance instead of `null` this time.

Comment: So, what do I need to have in dbCreds.php file?

Comment: Four variables. I'll put that in the answer.

Comment: @Ok, I updated `getMySQLi()` and added `dbCreds.php`. Make sure to copy a new `getMySQLi()` function from the site, as I updated the variable names to match the PHP Manual for the `MySQLi:: __construct` (constructor).

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues with your code, such as:

- You're creating a new table in each iteration of `while()` loop.
- You're using the same *div* ids, `element1` and `content1` for all of your table rows. Use `class` instead. However, based on your question,

  > I would like every new element to appear one next to the other.

  You can use the `id` attributes there, but you have to take the entire `<table> ... <div id="content1">` and `<div id="hovers"> ... </table>` out of the `while()` loop. And of course, change `id="hovers"` to `class="hovers"` and the associated CSS accordingly.

So **the solution** code would be like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <div id="element1"></div>
        <div id="content1">
        <?php 
            while($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($featured)){
                ?>
                <td>
                    <img src="<?= $product['image']; ?>" alt="<?= $product['title']; ?>">
                    <h4><?= $product['title']; ?></h4>
                    <hr>
                    <p class="description"><?= $product['description']; ?></p>

                    <!--------BUTTON 3-------->
                    <div class="hovers">
                        <a href="#" class="button">
                            <span class="contentbut"> Read More</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <?php
            }
        ?>
        </div>
    </tr>
</table>
```

#### Update(1):

From [**OP's comment**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42471993/how-to-display-data-from-mysql-database-in-a-row/42472348?noredirect=1#comment72088629_42472348),

> I am trying to have 3 interviews in a row and several rows with interviews.

The solution would be to have three table cells in each row,

```
<table>
    <div id="element1"></div>
    <div id="content1">
        <tr>
        <?php 
            $counter = 1;
            while($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($featured)){
                if($counter % 4 == 0){
                    echo '</tr><tr>';
                }
                ++$counter;
                ?>
                <td>
                    <img src="<?= $product['image']; ?>" alt="<?= $product['title']; ?>">
                    <h4><?= $product['title']; ?></h4>
                    <hr>
                    <p class="description"><?= $product['description']; ?></p>

                    <!--------BUTTON 3-------->
                    <div class="hovers">
                        <a href="#" class="button">
                            <span class="contentbut"> Read More</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <?php
            }
        ?>
        </tr>
    </div>
</table>
```

Comment: I wonder if he really wants to make a new table for each record....I'm guessing no.

Comment: Yes. I am trying to have 3 interviews in a row  and several rows with interviews. I will check your suggestions and will let you know if I have any questions. Thank you.

Comment: Putting loops in HTML is not a great idea.

Comment: Not the ideal solution, even for a simple page.

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge I know. Even my answer says so, OP should not create a new table in each iteration of `while()` loop.

Comment: Yes, true, but why put the loop in the HTML? It is legal syntax, but a maintenance nightmare. My solution is not great for maintenance (as you have to alter a method to change the structure of a table data cell), but it interferes less with the page generally.

Comment: @Kaloyan Ah, now with your comment, the question became much more clear. I'm at the office right now, will update the answer once I reach home.

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge With OP's comment *I am trying to have 3 interviews in a row and several rows with interviews.*, I believe the `whie()` loop is mandatory here. However, I've to tweak the code just a little bit. Will do so.

Comment: @Kaloyan I've updated my answer. Please see the **Update(1)** section of my answer. Hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Comment: @Melinda How? The answer is perfectly aligned with OP's question.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul Hello, friend. You may accomplish something, but at the high cost of *mixing concerns*. I try to avoid doing loops in HTML at all costs.  I think the introduction to my answer sums up the problem with your answer, even it it works.