# Adding elements from a MYSQL query to a HTML Table using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to output results from a MYSQL query into a HTML table using PHP. I am very new to this field and I read all the related questions but cant figure it out. I am sure the error is just a minor one.

Here is my PHP

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($db);

if($mysqli -> connect_error)
{
    die("Connect Error (".$mysqli -> connect_errno.") ".$mysqli -> connect_error);
}

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM 'Users'");

$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

$mysqli->close();
```

And here is the snippet of the HTML table

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo "$row[1]"; ?></td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>48</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What's your problem or question?

Comment: Oh, well, its not appearing on the webpage. So, the echo statement is not working. I dont know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shouldn't put table name in quotes.

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM Users");
echo '<table>';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo '<tr>';
    // assuming table(User) have fields like id,name
    echo '<td>'.$row['id'].'</td>'; 
    echo '<td>'.$row['name'].'</td>'; //name is column name
    echo '</tr>';
  }
  echo '</table>';
  $mysqli->close();
```

Comment: For a more flexible and robust answer, look here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42471993/how-to-display-data-from-mysql-database-in-a-row/42473747#42473747